# How to parse an array with strings using Java Stream API

Tags: java, java-stream

How to use Java stream API to parse and create a hashmap from an array of strings with two different delimiters.

I have the following Array

```
String[] domaintCount = new String[]{  "900, google.com",
                                          "400, mobile.yahoo.co.uk",
                                           "100, mobile.amazon.com",
                                           "100, samsung.com"
                                            } ;
```

I wanted to create a hashmap with each word as key and number as value..
For example

```
google ,900,
com ,900,
mobile,400
```

etc.. I wanted to do it using Stream API functions.

Comment: What should the value of com map to -> 900 from google.com or 100 from samsung.com?

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this. The basic idea is to split the strings into maps of `<domain, number>`, then merge those maps' values.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] domaintCount = new String[]
    {
            "900, google.com",
            "400, mobile.yahoo.co.uk",
            "100, mobile.amazon.com",
            "100, samsung.com"
    };

    Function<String, Map<String, String>> stringParser = string -> {
        String[] splitByComma = string.split(", ");
        String num = splitByComma[0];
        String[] domains = splitByComma[1].trim().split("\\.");
        Map<String, String> stringStringHashMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (String dom : domains) {
            stringStringHashMap.put(dom, num);
        }
        return stringStringHashMap;
    };

    Map<String, String> collect = Stream.of(domaintCount)
            .map(stringParser)
            .map(Map::entrySet)
            .flatMap(Set::stream)
            .collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue))
            .values().stream()
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (v1, v2) -> v1));

    System.out.println(collect);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would split and then collect it into a Map. For your simple case, I have used the SimpleEntry from Java directly. If your result is more complex, I would have created a pojo:

```
Map<String, Double> yourMap = Arrays.stream(domaintCount)
    .map(string -> {
      String[] splitted = string.split(",");
      return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, Double>(splitted[1].trim(), Double.valueOf(splitted[0].trim()));
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey, AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getValue));
```

Answer (score 0):

This way you can use ", " and " ," as well.

```
Stream.of(domainCount)
.map(str->str.split(", "))
.collect(toMap(strArr->strArr[0].trim(), strArr->strArr[1].trim());
```

Comment: I couldn't edit due to 404 error, but instead of split(", ") I meant split(",")

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] domaintCount = new String[]{  "900, google.com",
            "400, mobile.yahoo.co.uk",
            "100, mobile.amazon.com",
            "100, samsung.com"
    };


    Arrays.stream(domaintCount)
            .map(s -> {
                String[] strings = s.split(",");
                return new Domain(Integer.valueOf(strings[0]), strings[1].trim());
            })
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}

static class Domain {
    private Integer count;
    private String dn;
    public Domain(Integer count, String dn) {
        this.count = count;
        this.dn = dn;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("[Domain, count: %d, dn: %s]", count, dn);
    }
}
```